# Annotation jpa @Query

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I am studying jpa and hibernate. I see in the repository class:

```java
@Query(value = "FROM AccountTable")
List<Account> findAllAccount();
```

Is `@Query(value = "FROM AccountTable")` equal to a `select * from AccountTable`, without filters? Is it correct?

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `@Query` is not jpa, but [spring data jpa annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select):

> The select statement in JPQL is exactly the same as for HQL except that JPQL requires a `select_clause`, whereas HQL does not.

So, the mentioned in your question query with HQL specific syntax equals to the following JPQL:

```java
@Query("select a FROM AccountTable a")
List<Account> findAllAccount();
```

Please note that the last one query is more clear and suggested as a good practice.

> *Even though HQL does not require the presence of a `select_clause`, it is generally good practice to include one.* For simple queries the intent is clear and so the intended result of the `select_clause` is easy to infer. But on more complex queries that is not always the case.
>
> It is usually better to explicitly specify intent. *Hibernate does not actually enforce that a select_clause be present even when parsing JPQL queries, however, applications interested in JPA portability should take heed of this.*